# CSS float align at top

Tags: css

What is the best way (without js) to make all cells align (ie, have three cells per row in this case).

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
    <li>Line1 this is a very long line that will break the layout</li>
    <li>Line2</li>
    <li>Line3</li>
    <li>Line4 this is a very long line that will break the layout</li>
    <li>Line5</li>
    <li>Line6</li>
    <li>Line7 this is a very long line that will break the layout</li>
    <li>Line8</li>
    <li>Line9</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#list li{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

**Result**

[image]

It can all be seen in [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mctu7/).

The number of items per line may change (ie, I don't know where the new line will start), and the height of each is variable (ie, cannot force height).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `vertical-align` to ensure that the text of the blocks are always at the top regardless of height.

```
#list li {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/v/vertical-align/

Comment: Link has died unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `clear:left;` on the first element of each new line.

With CSS3 you can do:

```
#list li:nth-of-type(3n+1) {
  clear:left;
}
```

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-nthoftype

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you mean, but they're aligned:

```
#list li{
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    min-height:40px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's my problem. The text might change and will break the layout. See http://jsfiddle.net/mctu7/3/ with your answer. Line 7 should come under line 4.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your css:

```
display: inline-block;
height: 3em; /* adjust to fit largest content in any of the blocks */
```

and reduce the width slightly - the 1px border is added to the width, so you're ending up with 100% + 6px, meaning only 2 blocks show up per line.

Answer (score 0):

```
#list li{
    display:inline-block;
    width: 30%;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NF7UY/

That's my solution

Answer (score 0):

The flex-box solution:

```
#list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; /*allows items to flow into a new row*/
}
#list li {
  width: 33%;
  border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

results in:

[image]

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xja40zod/2/